# Understanding a summation algorithm

Tags: algorithm

How does the following work?

```
Algorithm 1 Sum of numbers in an Array
Function SUMMATION (Sequence)
    sum <---0
    for i <----1 to Length (Sequence) do
        Sum <--- Sum + sequence[i]
    end for
    return sum
```

Comment: See the [summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) wikipedia entry.

Comment: `what happens when you no longer accept questions from an account here? do i just open another account?` - No, you revist your account and try to improve your questions and provide some answers

Answer (score 4):

It's basically saying that if you start at the beginning of an array (its first element), and at every element add that element's value to a running total, when you reach the last element (the length of the sequence) you'll have the sum of the values of the array.

```
# This says "we have a function called SUMMATION. It requires a sequence
Function SUMMATION (Sequence)
# This says "assign the value 0 to variable 'sum'
sum <---0
# This says "make variable 'i' go from 1 to the length of the sequence"
for i <----1 to Length (Sequence) do
    # This says "assign 'sum + the ith value in the sequence' to variable 'sum'
    Sum <--- Sum + sequence[i]
# This indicates we're done with the loop, so loop back to the top, or
# continue on if we're done looping
end for
# This just returns the value 'sum' to the calling procedure
return sum
```

What we have here isn't in any particular language. Instead, it's "Pseudocode" - it's meant to look enough like code in order to convey an algorithm or other code-related idea, but is intentionally meant to not be in a particular language. In this manner, it's more readily accessible to anyone who reads code without requiring they have knowledge of a particular language.

Answer (score 0):

Translated to java?

```
int algorithm (int[] array) {

  int sum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: If you're truly going to translate it to Java, you'd want to keep in mind that this can easily overflow.